# Qt: How to cancel ALL processing of a QtConcurrent::map()?

Tags: multithreading, qt, concurrency, parallel-processing, cancellation

I am using Qt5 on Windows7 platform.

In my current application I am using `QtConcurrent` to process all items in a container.
If I decide to exit the application, I am using: `QFuture::cancel()`.
As per documentation http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfuture.html#cancel, not **all** async computations are canceled. Probably are canceled only the ones that are not yet started? And the running/ongoing computations are still allowed to continue to run?

If the above assumption is correct and `QFuture::cancel()` is **not** sufficient, then what should I do in order to stop also the running (ongoing) processing and exit the application gracefully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot pre-emptively and gracefully terminate asynchronous operations. The operations themselves must support co-operative cancellation.

In other words, it's impossible for any framework, library, or operating system to provide this functionality for you. You must handle cancelling operations that have already started yourself.

Comment: So, you're saying it is **not** possible to force stopping the computations `from outside` the processing threads? Then is there a `common/best practice` to achieve that (stop all running threads)? Is there something (implementation) specific to Qt?

Comment: @groenhen The key part in their answer is cannot **gracefully** terminate. Of course, you can terminate/kill a thread/process but that is usually not the way to proceed. I'm not sure if Qt exposes a way to do it in the interface you're using.

Comment: @groenhen To gracefully cancel you need to build that logic into your processing. For example, if the algorithm is driven by a loop each loop iteration could check if the operation has been canceled and exit the loop (i.e., without going through all iterations of the loop).

Comment: @JamesAdkison: Some sort of `while (external_cancel_requested == false)  { processing(); }` will be in the spirit of your suggestion? ... where `external_cancel_requested` is boolean volatile variable?

Comment: @groenhen I think you have the idea but the code you posted would run `processing` infinitely until a cancel occurs, which is probably not what is intended. In this case, you'd probably want to drill down into `processing` and figure out places where the `cancel` flag can be checked to exit early.

Comment: @JamesAdkison Does Qt, then, provide this `cancel` flag, that got set by the framework when the QFuture was canceled? I'd suppose so, but didn't find it in the docs.  (Am currently looking into a simmilar problem...)